# ASP JIT debugger not breaking (ASP Classic)

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, asp-classic, visual-studio-debugging

Attempting to put a `Stop` statement in my ASP page, and the JIT debugger is NOT breaking.

I have tried and double checked all the basics (Enable server-side debugging in on, etc.)

This used to work a few months ago.

Here is the setup:

- Windows 7 64x
- Visual Studio 2008
- Visual Studio 2012
- IIS 7

Any ideas?

Comment: is your OS Windows 8?

Comment: No, running Windows 7.

Comment: I have fixed the issue, however I would not consider this a "fix" as I have not tracked down the source issue. I Uninstalled and re-installed  the "ASP" feature in Windows, which apparently re-registered *something* and fixed my debugging issue. I cannot attribute the fix to a particular problem however.

Comment: i think there is an issue when you install visual Studio 2012 AFTER you have activated classic asp. the reactivation of classic asp AFTER the Installation of visual Studio 2012 then "repairs" that issue...